# how to rename/drop a specific column in sql plus?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table called **employee** and it contain three columns **eid,ename,sal** in sql plus.
and how to change the column **'sal'** to **'salary'**?.

Comment: Your google search string is "oracle rename column".

Answer (score 2):

Use the **RENAME COLUMN** statement to rename a column in a table.

```
alter table employee rename column sal to salary
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following sentence:

```
alter table employee rename column sal to salary;
```

Reference: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rename_column_table.htm

Comment: i got the error, 'Error at line 1: ORA-14004, missing PARTITION keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of memorizing the syntax for every operation you wish to do, a good approach to learn is to use an IDE like Toad or SQL Developer and look for the "Show SQL" option.  For example, in Toad, you can right click on a table in the schema browser, choose alter table, and change the column name.  Instead of just accepting the changes (OK), you can hit the "Show SQL" button on bottom left, which will show you the SQL to be executed (in this case, the alter table rename syntax).

The other way to help yourself in the future is to refer to the [Oracle SQL Reference documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001).

Comment: 'alter table employee rename column sal to salary;' not working with oracle 8.0.3.0.0. got this error 'ORA-14004, missing PARTITION keyword'.

Comment: Oracle 8?  I remember using that in the late 90s I think.  Not sure for this version, should be same syntax I think, but check google for the old 8 docs.